# INSERT Pandas Dataframe to SQL-Server using Python - Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas

Till now, I've been requesting data from my SQL-server, using an API, `php` file basically and using the `requests` module in Python. So here's my code for that:

```
# importing the requests library
import requests

# api-endpoint
URL = "https://******.co.in/******/queryRandom.php"

# location given here
token= '***************'

query= 'SELECT userId,createdAt,.... FROM xyz WHERE date >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 60 DAY'

# defining a params dict for the parameters to be sent to the API
PARAMS = {'token':token, 'query':query}

# sending get request and saving the response as response object
r = requests.post(url = URL, data = PARAMS)
df=pd.DataFrame(r.json())
df.head()
```

Now after I'm done with my work, I formed a dataframe like this:

```
Sl.No.  date    nameofthepic    
1   26-08-2018  10-must-see-waterfalls-in-karnataka-8081714182d8    
2   26-08-2018  a-month-in-backpack-one-girl-one-goal-to-explore-the-himalayas-22813ee67e15 
3   26-08-2018  a-month-in-backpack-one-girl-one-goal-to-explore-the-himalayas-week-1-8d113ee673db  
4   26-08-2018  a-month-in-backpack-one-girl-one-goal-to-explore-the-himalayas-week-1-22b13ee67b87  
5   26-08-2018  backpacking-for-a-month-in-the-himalayas-week-1-30813ee674a6
```

Now using the similar `requests` module, is there a way I can write something like this: `INSERT INTO table_name...` and upload the dataframe into the SQL table.

The main problem I'm not able to figure out is:

i) How do I upload the dataframe column values into the table in one go?

ii) If its not possible through requests module, is there any other way I can upload the Pandas dataframe values into SQL-server table directly from `jupyter-notebook` using Python code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To import this dataframe into a MySQL table:

```
# Import dataframe into MySQL
import sqlalchemy
database_username = 'ENTER USERNAME'
database_password = 'ENTER USERNAME PASSWORD'
database_ip       = 'ENTER DATABASE IP'
database_name     = 'ENTER DATABASE NAME'
database_connection = sqlalchemy.create_engine('mysql+mysqlconnector://{0}:{1}@{2}/{3}'.format(database_username, database_password, database_ip, database_name))
frame.to_sql(con=database_connection, name='table_name_for_df', if_exists='append')
```

Comment: but this will replace the table everytime i run the code right?! I want it to append everyday's data

Comment: if_exists='append' will append everyday data to mysql database